# Assumption in black scholes solution

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde

Under the usual notations,

In most textbooks on Quantative Finance, for deriving the Black-Scholes solution I find that authors, while setting up the riskless portfolio, assume that,

$$\text{d} (\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} S_t) =  \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \text{d} S_t $$

At least can we prove this post facto, as in, does this equation hold true for famous Black Scholes equation

The same issue is also pointed out [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8560/black-scholes-hedging-argument?rq=1).

Comment: Uhm, so you're saying your question is a duplicate? I see that the question you link to also has an answer. Where do you require further clarification?

Comment: The answers to that question are not accepted; Also, while the question is similar, what I am asking is a slightly more different one. If someone were to answer this question, probably a part of the linked question would be answered.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely my question!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Note that $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t} = N(d_1)$. Then
\begin{align*}
d\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t}S_t\right) &= \underbrace{S_t dN(d_1) + d\langle N(d_1), S\rangle_t} + N(d_1) dS_t\\
&\ne N(d_1) S_t.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
d\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t}S_t\right)\ne \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_t}dS_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: $${S_t dN(d_1) + d\langle N(d_1), S\rangle_t}$$ can this be negligible ? Why I'm asking is that textbooks like Hull are rarely wrong in these matters. I hope I am making myself clear.

Comment: It is not negligible, as there is diffusion term which can take any values. Textbooks like Hull's did made a mistake here. See discussions in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging/34059#34059) and also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential/32187#32187).